# Backing up iOS Health Data takes enormous space?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, health.app

I got an auto generated e-mail from Apple telling me that my iCould Drive was almost full

> Dear Benny Skogberg,
>
> Your iCloud storage is almost full. You have
> 499.728 MB remaining of 5 GB total storage.
>
> ```
>             Upgrade to 50 GB for 9,00 kr per month
> ```
>
> Your iCloud storage is used for iCloud Mail and to keep
> the most important things on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch safe
> and available, even if you lose your device. iCloud Drive and apps
> like Keynote, Pages, and Numbers also use iCloud storage to keep your
> files up-to-date everywhere. To continue to use iCloud and to back up
> your photos, documents, contacts, mail, and more, you need to upgrade
> your iCloud storage plan or reduce the amount of storage you are
> using.
>
> The iCloud Team

Looking into the Backup, I saw the health data used more than half of the backup for it's data, and I come to think why. Do they store videos/images of health data? Other apps are less than 100 MB.

What makes the Health Data generate Gigabytes of Backup data?

[image]

Comment: On mine, Health was up to 5 gigabytes back in September. I brought that down to about 2 gigs by deleting a ton of older data. But I'm creeping towards 4 gigs once again. I do exercise daily with an Apple Watch (hence, lots of heart rate and steps data), but gigabytes over a few months still seems excessive. iCloud backups fail every other night as result, due to the sheer amount of data to upload. I don't recall Health data ballooning like this until iOS 9 (which may have caused all the backup issues at the time). It looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long have you kept your iPhone? For many years? The Health App stores data of your steps, walking + Running Distance, fights Climbed, etc.

You can just turn off & delete the Health App data from iCloud backup.

Or go to *Health > steps > Show All Data > Edit >　Deleted All* data from the app.

Comment: This iPhone I've used for 1,5 years, but I've used the Health App on other devices since release, which have collected data through the years. I've restored new iPhones with old backups. But collecting steps for three years doesn't (or shouldn't) render 2,2 GB of data. Either someone is collecting far more data than I can imagine, or there is something terribly wrong. 1 GB is the equivalent of 20'000 pages of text. See: http://www.v-rooms.com/technology/how-much-data-is-in-1GB.php